# How to stop JW player control bar from fading out during playing? (JW 8)

Tags: jwplayer

I am currently using JWplayer as a video player for an experiment test.

The timestamp of the video is really important in my case when people provide some responses to the certain spot in the video. People could hover the mouse on the video, however, it's very inconvenient as they need to use the mouse to click on something else at the same time.

So I wonder if there is a way to keep the controlbar/(most importantly the time slider) showing up all the time during playing?

I have checked the JWplayer API reference however it looks I can only disable the control bar or let it fade away after a short while.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add this style to your player, in the head tag or wherever it makes sense for you:

```
  <style>
    .jwplayer.jw-state-idle .jw-controlbar {display: table;}
    </style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  But does it apply to jwplayer 8? I both tried to add this to the head of index.html, as well as the style.css my pages uses, the player still autohide however....